# Flatten a map into pairs (key, value) in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, flatmap

Say I construct the following map in scala:

```
val map = Map.empty[String, Seq[String]] + ("A" -> ("1", "2", "3", "4"), "B" -> ("2", "3"), "C" -> ("3", "4"))
```

My output should be a Sequence of single key, value pairs. Namely, it should look like this:

```
[("A", "1"), ("A", "2"), ("A", "3"), ("A", "4"), ("B", "2"), ("B", "3"), ("B", "2"), ("C", "3"),
("C", "4")]
```

How can I obtain this using flatMap?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far? You almost already have the answer in your question `flatMap`.

Comment: I'm kind of stacked because I tried different things but I keep getting type errors.

Comment: What are the different things that you tried, and what type errors were you getting?
Check this resource out on how to ask good questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your original goal was to create next map (note added `Seq`s in map):

```scala
val map = Map.empty[String, Seq[String]] + ("A" -> Seq("1", "2", "3", "4"), "B" -> Seq("2", "3"), "C" -> Seq("3", "4"))
```

Then you will be able to easily transform it easily with:

```scala
val result = map.toSeq.flatMap { case (k, v) => v.map((k, _)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can create the map directly, no need appending to an empty map.

```scala
val map = Map("A" -> Seq("1", "2", "3", "4"), "B" -> Seq("2", "3"), "C" -> Seq("3", "4"))
```

Comment: I believe this should be a comment rather than an answer but absolutely right.